# Оптимизация node.js

Tags: javascript, ооп, node.js, оптимизация

Привет всем, решил занятся обучением Node.js. Начал обучение с сокетами. И столкнулся с таким вопросом:
Разработал алгоритм оповещения позицией объекта клиентов, хотел бы узнать, правильно ли я сделал с точки зрения оптимизации, если нет подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибки

```
var CurrentX;
var EndX;

data.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('GetX', function (data) {

       CurrentX = 0;
       EndX = data;


       var interval = setInterval(function() {
           CurrentX++;
           socket.emit('message', Xpos);
           socket.broadcast.emit('message', Xpos);
       }, 50);

       if (CurrentX == EndX) {
       clearInterval(interval);
    }
});
```

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 2):

#### Потенциальные проблемы

1. Страшно видеть `socket.on` и `setInterval` в связке) Cерия повторных запросов GetX с одного клиента запустит N интервалов с частотой 50мс. Помимо бессмысленного потребления ресурсов сервер начнет спамить сообщениями 'message' в N раз чаще. Используйте `socket.once`
2. `if(CurrentX == EndX)` - недобрый клиент отсылает data=-1 и ваш интервал не прекратится никогда. Попробуйте `CurrentX >= EndX` или проверку `data` на корректность. 
   **Золотое правило - "нельзя верить клиенту")**
3. <strike>`broadcast.emit` отсылает координаты текущего объекта ВСЕМ соединениям, в том числе и текущему соединению. Налицо дублирование пересылаемых данных.</strike> [Был неправ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474114/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-node-js/474422?noredirect=1#comment535890_474422)

#### Общие мысли

Если вы пишете что-то вроде игры, можно организовать оповещение немного иначе:

1. На сервере в памяти хранить список координат объектов на текущей "карте"
2. Отдельными событиями типа "передвижение" клиенты меняют информацию этой "карте".
3. Нового подключенного клиента подписать на получение актуальной карты через заданный интервал. (Преимущество перед `broadcast` - мы можем отсылать не одну глобальную карту на всех, а локальные карты, актуальные для текущего клиента, предполагая изменения за их пределами несущественными)
4. При отключении клиента интервал очистить.

Comment: " Broadcasting means sending a message to everyone else except for the socket that starts it." [Источник](http://socket.io/docs/).

Comment: @D-side: хорошее определение.

Comment: @NickVolynkin пресловутое "naming things".

Comment: Интервал там и так никогда не очищается, т. к. проверка на отключение делается снаружи, а не внутри.